# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2008R2 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have just installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. I haven't set anything unusual during the installation process. Everything was default, that the instance name is `SQLExpress`, the connection is via SQL Server with user `sa` and my password. I have opened SQL Server Configuration Manager and I can see under `SQL Express Service`, `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)`'s state is `running`. Yet, it does not let me get connected :/

I am using Commodo Internet Security. I have looked at Firewall Log and it says only that Windows Operating System is blocked. I set CIS to ask for every connection and it doesn't show anything. I am not sure if it's it.

Any idea how to diagnose the problem? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Under the Server Name, I provide `SQLEXPRESS` which was the set name while installing the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As server name, you need to use

```
.\SQLEXPRESS    or    (local)\SQLEXPRESS
```

where the dot `.` stands for the local machine - `SQLEXPRESS` is the name of the **instance** (not the server name itself)

Comment: It works :)
I also went to `Broswe for more` and it did not show anything until I have changed CIS to ask for each network connection. Eventually CIS showed something beginning with `Ss...`. And then it found my computer name. So frustrating! Thanks for your help!

Comment: If SQLEXPRESS is the name of an instance, can I set / install more instances?

Comment: @ZikO: **yes, of course!** Since SQL Server **2000**, you can have *one default* instance (without an explicit instance name), and almost multiple (up to 50) **named instances** of various versions, if you like